# QStatusBar.showMessage issue:

Tags: pyqt4

I have got 2 situation when trying to call QStatusBar.showMessage().
 - 1st: Got error: `TypeError: 'QStatusBar' object is not callable`
 - 2nd: It does not effect and nothing happen. I got a blank status bar, without any error message.

## Here the detail:

### The MainWindow class:

```
    self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
```

This module has been imported to the main file. Then, in the main file, I have called `QtGui.QStatusBar`'s `showMessage()` method, and got two following issues.

### 1. TypeError: 'QStatusBar' object is not callable

I have used following code statement to call `QtGui.QStatusBar`'s `showMessage()` method:
    `self.ui.statusbar().showMessage("You have selected: %s" % self.filename, msecs= 5)`

### 2. A blank statusbar; no effect and there's any error message.

I have used this code statement:
    `self.ui.statusbar.showMessage("You have selected: %s" % self.filename, msecs= 5)`
I haven't got any error, but it's also take no effect.

Someone can help me to figure out that what I have wrong and how to fix it? Thank you!

Comment: `msecs=5` will make that message appear for 5 miliseconds, and then clear it. It will be hardly noticeable. You can use `0` for permanent message, or use a value that is noticeable like a few seconds.

Comment: Thank you! :)
I have misunderstood something, the value is in milisecond but not second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `msecs= 5`.
This means "show the message for 5 milliseconds"!
Please try with `msecs=5000`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the '()' behind 'statusbar' because it is isn't a method.

Comment: Sure ,the argument 'msecs' is important.